# How to combine identical ftplugin files?

Tags: vimscript, ftplugin

I am trying to write a plugin and I observed that I have identical `ftplugin` files. e.g. `ftplugin/python.vim` and `ftplugin/julia.vim` have exactly the same content and it looks like the following:

```
vim9script 

import autoload "../myfunctions.vim"

b:some_var = g:plugins_some_var[&filetype]

augroup my_group
    autocmd! * <buffer>
    autocmd BufEnter <buffer> myfunctions.MyFunc()
augroup END
```

How can I re-arrange my code structure to avoid such repetitions?

Answer (score 1):

May be you could move that code into a plugin file and in the autocommand, you test for the existence of `&ft` key in your `g:plugins_some_var` global variable. If so, you call the function.

Comment: I tried to add `b:some_var = get(g:plugins_some_var, &filetype, "")` to `plugin/myplugin.vim` but either if I open a `python` file or exactly `myplugin.vim` and run `:echo b:some_var` I get `E121: Undefined variable: b:some_var`. I think - but I may be wrong - that the mechanism won't work because `myplugin.vim` is sourced only once. Hence, if I change file `b:some_var = get(g:plugins_some_var, &filetype, "")` won't be executed.

Comment: Never define buffer variables in global scope of plugin files. In functions called from buffer related events, only then it could make sense (or in the global scope of ftplugin files as they are sourced on buffer related events)

Comment: Exactly. It would be weird to have b: variables in plugin files. In-fact it didn't work.

Comment: I usually simply put my functions in autoload plugins. And if I need ft specialized functions, I would have `autoload/{myinitials}/{filetype}/{pluginname}.vim` (with vimscript 1 at least. I've never tried the new scripting language from vim 9)

Comment: I never used the former vimscript instead, I started like two months ago and I decided to start directly with the new. It doesn’t look much different though. Regarding the autoload mechanism you can place your files wherever you want and use import autoload, i.e. you don’t need to place stuff necessarily to’ autoload folder in vim9script.

Answer (score 0):

Just use symlinks. This is the easiest possible solution.